# Use local variable string from extended class in another class

Tags: java, http, inheritance, rest-assured

So, I have a local variable of type String in a class.

```
public class QueryEndpoint {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {

        String username = "username111";
        String password = "password222";
        StringBuilder authorization = new StringBuilder();
        authorization.append(username).append(":").append(password);
        String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authorization.toString().getBytes());
    }
```

In another class which extends the above, I have

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.jayway.restassured.authentication.PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme;
import com.example.misc.QueryEndpoint;

public class ApiTest extends QueryEndpoint {

    @Test
    public void verifyTopLevelURL() {
        given()
                .header("Authorization", authScheme) // <--HERE
                .contentType("application/json")
                .when().get("/22222222").then()
                .body("fruit",equalTo("22222222"))
                .body("fruit.apple",equalTo(37))
                .body("fruit.banana",equalTo("111"))
                .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

How do I access String authHeader in class ApiTest from QueryEndpoint? It says cannot resolve symbol 'authScheme'

Comment: Those variable are all inside a method, they can't even be accessed in other methods of the same class, much less from other classes. Put them to class level or let the user enter them if possible (at least the password).

Comment: *I have a local variable*... You seem to understand the scope of the variable, so what have you tried to change that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try by making `authHeader` a static variable

```
public class QueryEndpoint {

    public static String authHeader;
```

As the scope of your local variable `authHeader` is only inside the braces it cannot be accessed by any other method.

You have to either pass it as an argument to a function or make it a class level variable.

Comment: While the code is right the description is **wrong**! The  making the variable `public` solvet the problem, not making it `static`...

Comment: No, because if we make it public and not static we have to create a new object of QueryEndpoint which will not have the value which he needs in another class function.
While making it static means the variable is associated with class, not its objects.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `protected` should work as well, and depending on the package even default visibility.

Comment: If he wants to make it package-private he can use protected, but making it static is what makes it work.

Comment: @Thomas right, I assume the classes actually are in different packages, the original version was *package private*

Comment: @GursheeshSingh No, you cannot access a *package private* `static` element from anothe package.

Comment: import com.example.misc.QueryEndpoint

from this statement we can see that Apitest and QueryEndpoint are in different packages.So public is what should be used